# How/Which directory to install a 3rd party C++ library on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, vcpkg

I'm just beginning to learn more about Linux as I'm using Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install a header-only library called "date.h" from [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)

An excerpt from the github states that this is a header-only library

> "date.h" is a header-only library which builds upon <chrono>. It adds some new duration types, and new time_point types. It also adds "field" types such as year_month_day which is a struct {year, month, day}. And it provides convenient means to convert between the "field" types and the time_point types.

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
vcpkg install date
```

I followed the above instruction and now I have `/home/username/vcpkg/` with many other directories underneath it.

I navigated to `/home/username/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/date` and found `date.h` and `tz.h`, which I were looking for.

I'm trying to use them in a C++ project but I'm not sure how to tell the compiler where to find the header files. Should I cut/copy paste `/date` directory into `/user/include/c++/9`, or `/usr/local/include`, or `/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`? or should I do none of those? Am I supposed to define the path to the library in my files/makefile somehow?

Thank you

Comment: What type of project is this? How do you build it?

Comment: I just throw header-only libraries directly in the source tree of the project that's using it. Failing that, `/usr/local/include`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass **VCPKG** toolchain file to **CMake**:

```
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
cmake --build build
```

Please adjust **DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE** to your **VCPKG** installation path.

If you would like to use [**VCPKG** manifest mode](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/manifests/) (with file that describes all dependent libraries), just add one more parameter "**-DVCPKG_FEATURE_FLAGS=versions**":

```
cmake -B build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_FEATURE_FLAGS=versions
cmake --build build
```